# How To Make Menu Slide In 3D?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, customization, menu

I saw it here:

http://theunlockr.com/2011/04/12/android-101-how-to-scan-use-a-qr-code/

Watch video and you will see. I want to know how to create this effect on Android Gingerbread.

Thanks.

Comment: The built-in launcher on the Nexus One does something very similar to that in the apps list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i flashed a custom [Gingerbread rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=758197), one of the launchers included has this menu style, but again, this includes rooting your phone and doing a data wipe at least once.

Launchers change the app menu style, but i do not know if this one is available without a custom ROM, which will require a root and reflash.

Comment: Since my smartphone is under warranty, i will forget about rooting.

Comment: rooting is simple to undo, and most providers won't worry about it when doing simple repairs and such. it's against my warranty as well, but i've had mine repaired and replaced several times without conflict. @Ryan's response is appropriate too, i had forgotten that launcher had that app drawer, but i've used it before, and can tell you it's a good choice!

Answer (score 0):

[ADW Launcher EX](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adwfreak.launcher&feature=search_result) is a replacement Launcher and it has the ability to have the "Application Drawer" in the 3D mode like you described. There is also a [free version](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.adw.launcher&feature=more_from_developer) that may have that option as well, I don't remember if it had it or not.

These can be installed on the device from the android market, and do not require rooting.